# How can I sort an array by the product/quotient of two values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of posts. Each post has 'views' and 'likes,' with the _ids of users in an array I want to sort the array by the like rate.

This doesn't work though.

```
posts.sort(function (a, b) {
   return (b.likes.length * 100) / b.views.length
});


{
 "title":"Post 1",
 "views":"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]",
 "likes":"[1, 2]"
}
{
 "title":"Post 2",
 "views":"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]",
 "likes":"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]"
}
{
 "title":"Post 3",
 "views":"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]",
 "likes":"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"}
}]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your array of posts, with maybe 3-4 posts so we have some sample data. We're not mind-readers

Comment: You need to return which of `a` and `b` is greater or smaller. Currently you're entirely ignoring the `a` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close, you're just forgetting to relate `a` and `b` to each other:

```
posts.sort(function (a, b) {
   var arate = (a.likes.length * 100) / a.views.length,
       brate = (b.likes.length * 100) / b.views.length;
   return arate - brate;
});
```

That will be in ascending order. If you want descending, change the return to `return brate - arate;`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's a lot easier than I thought it would be.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I would sort those results by views? So that even if two posts have the same likes rate, the one with the most views comes first.

Comment: You would need to do a secondary comparison. `if (arate === brate) { return a.views.length - b.views.length; } return arate - brate;`

Comment: @Nubby: See Evan's excellent reply above. Or as a one-liner: `return arate === brate ? a.views.length - b.views.length : arate - brate;` Note that in both cases (Evan's and mine), you might consider rounding `arate` / `brate` a bit (two places, perhaps) so that you don't have the `23.0000001` results after the `23.00` results.

Comment: I see. So whenever I want to add another comparison, I just attach it to the end of the sequence. So I could then place `if (a.views === b.views) { return a.publish_date - b.publish_date; } return arate - brate;` after the 'views' comparison to compare how soon a post was published.

Comment: @Nubby: Yup. If you have more than two criteria (rate and views), I'd definitely use `if` (as in Evan's answer) rather than a conditional operator, for clarity. Probably like this: `if (arate !== brate) { return arate - brate; }` then `if (a.views.length !== b.views.length) { return a.views.length - b.views.length; }` then `return a.publish_date = b.publish_date;`. But I wouldn't implement it within the sort iterator if it's non-trivial; instead, I'd have a function to compare two posts, like `localeCompare` does for strings.